# how to disable a specific css element from js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

So I have a html table that has a scroller(its a long table) and a search bar.The table is so long in fact that i dont want the user to be able to scroll down until they have typed a few letters in the search bar and the table has been shortened. Here is the css :

```
.table{
display: block;
height: 100px;
 overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden; 
}
```

how do i disable the "overflow-y: scroll" in code?

Comment: Try `$(".table").css("overflow-y", "none");`

Comment: Here is another solution to disable scroll http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily

Answer (score 1):

With javascript

```
document.getElementById("element_id").style.overflow = 'hidden';
```

Disable scroll events found here

[How to disable scrolling temporarily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily)

With jquery

```
$(".table").css("overflow-y", "none");
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is using jQuery.

```
if($('#div').html().length >0)
     $('.table').css('overflow-y','scroll');
else
     $('.table').css('overflow-y','hidden');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getComputedStyle()` to check the value of `overflow-y` if you need to toggle it. Otherwise set it directly with the `style` property.

```js
var target = document.querySelector( 'div' );
var btn    = document.querySelector( 'button' );

btn.addEventListener( 'click', function ( e ) {

  var overflowY = getComputedStyle( target ).overflowY;
  
  target.style.overflowY = 'scroll' === overflowY ? 'initial' : 'scroll';

} );
```

```css
div {
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<button>Change Overflow Y</button>

<div>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor.
  </p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor.
  </p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor.
  </p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor.
  </p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor.
  </p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor.
  </p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor.
  </p>
  
</div>
```

You could also use `auto` in place of `scroll` in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't touch the CSS and need to use javascript:

```
var table = document.querySelector('.table');

table.style.overflowY='hidden';
```

Hope that helps